# MySQL: Join three tables and show total count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following three tables (simplified):

```
User ( 
    UserID
    UserName
) 

UserMsg ( 
   toUserID
    MsgID
   theMsg
```

)

```
UserMsgComment ( 
   CommentID, 
  MsgID, 
 theComment 
)
```

And want to display the UserMsg-s each User has alongside with the count of the UserMsgComment of each UserMsg. If there is no UserMsgComment for a UserMsg, I want to show '0'.

```
  UserName | UserMsg | COUNT(UserMsgComment) or show '0' 


SELECT u.*, m.theMsg FROM User u, 
LEFT JOIN UserMsg m ON u.UserID = m.toUserID
```

How do I have to modify this query to show me the total count of UserMsgComment for each UserMsg or 0 if there is no entry in UserMsgComment?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` which is actually an `INNER JOIN`. A `LEFT JOIN` basically says "if no relation exists, show the row from the original table anyway".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to join on the extra table and group accordingly. Note that if you want to select u.* then you must group by each column in the User table also.

```
SELECT u.UserID, m.theMsg, COUNT(mc.CommentID)
FROM User u, 
LEFT JOIN UserMsg m ON u.UserID = m.toUserID
LEFT JOIN UserMsgComment mc on m.MsgID = mc.MsgID
GROUP BY u.UserID, m.theMsg
```

Comment: I've played around a little with your solution. Why would this query not work without the GROUP BY expression?

Comment: When using aggregate functions, such as COUNT, SUM, etc, you need to GROUP BY all of the columns which you are not applying aggregated functions to.

Comment: Thanks. Do you happen to have a link for me where this rule is explained in depth?

Comment: Here is the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html